# Getting error while trying to write program with overloaded operators

Tags: c++, class

I recently got an assignment that asks to convert my previous existing code using classes and normal member functions to a program that utilizes overloaded operators for the computations. I think I've got what to do but I'm still not familiar with specific things like getting the value. In the previous build I used a setter/getter but in this its providing an error that states "no matching function for call to 'Rational::setnumer(Rational)'. " I'm not sure how I would work around this or if a setter/getter would work in this case, my code is below:

```
using namespace std;

class Rational
{
    private:
        int numer;
        int denomer;

    public:
        // Default constructor that initializes objects to 0
        Rational()
        {
            this -> numer = 0;
            this -> denomer = 0;
        }

        // Get member function
        int getnumer()
        {
            return numer;
        }

        // Set member function
        void setnumer(int n)
        {
            this -> numer = n;
        }

        // Get member function
        int getdenomer ()
        {
            return denomer;
        }

        // Set member function
        void setdenomer (int d)
        {
            this -> denomer = d;
        }

        // Constructor to represent rationals as two integers
        Rational(int n, int d)
        {
            this -> numer = n;
            this -> denomer = d;
        }

        // Constructor with single int parameter
        Rational (int whole_number)
        {
            this -> numer = whole_number;
            this -> denomer = 1;
        }

        // Function that prints the sum
        void printNumber()
        {
            cout << getnumer() << "/" << getdenomer();
        }

        // Overload output operator
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, const Rational r1);

        // Input stream function (not in use since no file to enter info from)
        friend istream& operator >> (istream& fin, const Rational r1);

        // Overload '==' operator
        bool operator == (const Rational& r1);
        bool operator < (const Rational& rl);
        bool operator <= (const Rational& r1);
        bool operator > (const Rational& r1);
        bool operator >= (const Rational& r1);
        Rational operator + (const Rational& r1);
        Rational operator - (const Rational& r1);
        Rational operator * (const Rational& r1);
        Rational operator / (const Rational& r1);


};

int main()
{
    int num1, den1, num2, den2;
    Rational r3;

    // Creates file to put data into
    ofstream fout("Rationals.txt", ios::app);

    // Asks for value inputs
    cout << "Please enter the first numerator value: ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Please enter the first denominator value: ";
    cin >> den1;

    cout << "Please enter the second numerator value: ";
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "Please enter the second denominator value: ";
    cin >> den2;

    // Performs addition calculation
    cout << "\nAddition: ";
    cout << num1 << " / " << den1 << " + " << num2 << " / " << den2 << " = ";
    Rational r1(num1, den1);
    Rational r2 (num2, den2);

    r3 = r1 + r2;
    r3.printNumber();
    fout << r3;

    return 0;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& fin, const Rational r1)
{
    Rational num1, den1, num2, den2;
    fin >> num1 >> den1 >> num2 >> den2;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, const Rational r1)
{
    Rational r2;
    fout << r2.getnumer() << "/" << r2.getdenomer() << "\n";

    return fout;
}

bool Rational::operator == (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r2;

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r2.getnumer();
    d = r2.getdenomer();

    return ((a * d) == (c * b));
}

bool Rational::operator < (const Rational& rl)
    {
            Rational a, b, c, d, r2;

            a = getnumer();
            b = getdenomer();
            c = r2.getnumer();
            d = r2.getdenomer();

            return ((a * b) < (c*b));
    }

bool Rational::operator <= (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r2;

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r2.getnumer();
    d = r2.getdenomer();

    return ((a * b) <= (c*b));
}

bool Rational::operator > (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r2;

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r2.getnumer();
    d = r2.getdenomer();

    return ((a * b) > (c*b));
}

bool Rational::operator >= (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r2;

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r2.getnumer();
    d = r2.getdenomer();

    return ((a * b) >= (c*b));
}


Rational Rational::operator + (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r, r2;

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r.getnumer();
    d = r.getdenomer();

    r2.setnumer((a * d) + (b * c));
    r2.setdenomer(b * d);

    return r2;
}

Rational Rational::operator - (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r, r2;

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r1.getnumer();
    d = r1.getdenomer();

    r2.setnumer(a * d - b * c);
    r2.setdenomer(b * d);

    return r2;
}

Rational Rational::operator * (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r, r2;

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r.getnumer();
    d = r.getdenomer();

    r2.setnumer(a * c);
    r2.setdenomer(b * d);

    return r2;
}

Rational Rational::operator / (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r, r2;

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r1.getnumer();
    d = r1.getdenomer();

    r2.setnumer(a * d);
    r2.setdenomer(c * b);

    return r2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors here.

Firstly, you forgot to include a few headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

Second, in your functions, all of your functions try to assign an `int` to a `Rational`, after calling `getnumer()` and `getdenomer()`

Thirdly, some of your functions are recursive:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& fin, const Rational r1)
{
    Rational num1, den1, num2, den2;
    fin >> num1 >> den1 >> num2 >> den2; //You are calling operator>> again!
    //Never returns a istream& (should be a "return fin;" here)
}
```

Fourthly, you are assigning an int to a Rational. Example:

```
bool Rational::operator >= (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r2;

    a = getnumer(); //a is a Rational, not an int
    b = getdenomer(); //same here
    c = r2.getnumer(); //same here, and r2 is the default, don't you mean r1?
    d = r2.getdenomer(); //same here, and r2 is the default, don't you mean r1?

    return ((a * b) >= (c*b));
}
```

Finally, you are using a non-`const` function on a `const` object. Example:

```
bool Rational::operator >= (const Rational& r1)
{
    Rational a, b, c, d, r2;

    a = getnumer(); //getnumer and getdenomer are not const fucntions, and are being used on a const object!
    b = getdenomer(); //same here
    c = r2.getnumer(); //same here
    d = r2.getdenomer(); //same here

    return ((a * b) >= (c*b));
}
```

This is the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream> //Remember to include this for the streams
#include <fstream> //for the filestream

using namespace std;

class Rational
{
private:
    int numer;
    int denomer;

public:
    // Default constructor that initializes objects to 0
    Rational()
    {
        this->numer = 0;
        this->denomer = 0;
    }

    // Get member function
    int getnumer() const //so we know it does not impact a const object
    {
        return numer;
    }

    // Set member function
    void setnumer(int n)
    {
        this->numer = n;
    }

    // Get member function
    int getdenomer() const //so we know it does not impact a const object
    {
        return denomer;
    }

    // Set member function
    void setdenomer(int d)
    {
        this->denomer = d;
    }

    // Constructor to represent rationals as two integers
    Rational(int n, int d)
    {
        this->numer = n;
        this->denomer = d;
    }

    // Constructor with single int parameter
    Rational(int whole_number)
    {
        this->numer = whole_number;
        this->denomer = 1;
    }

    // Function that prints the sum
    void printNumber()
    {
        cout << getnumer() << "/" << getdenomer();
    }

    // Overload output operator
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, const Rational r1);

    // Input stream function (not in use since no file to enter info from)
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& fin, const Rational r1);

    // Overload '==' operator
    bool operator == (const Rational& r1);
    bool operator < (const Rational& rl);
    bool operator <= (const Rational& r1);
    bool operator > (const Rational& r1);
    bool operator >= (const Rational& r1);
    Rational operator + (const Rational& r1);
    Rational operator - (const Rational& r1);
    Rational operator * (const Rational& r1);
    Rational operator / (const Rational& r1);


};

istream& operator >> (istream& fin, const Rational r1)
{
    fin >> r1.numer >> r1.denomer; //note the non recursive-ness
    return fin; //note the returning
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& fout, const Rational r1)
{
    Rational r2;
    fout << r2.getnumer() << "/" << r2.getdenomer() << "\n";
    return fout; //note the returning
}

Rational Rational::operator*(const Rational& r) {
    return Rational(this->numer * r.numer, this->denomer * r.denomer); //simplified, does not reduce
}

Rational Rational::operator/(const Rational& r) {
    return Rational(this->numer / r.numer, this->denomer / r.denomer); //simplified, does not reduce
}

Rational Rational::operator-(const Rational& r) {
    if (this->denomer == r.denomer) return Rational(this->numer - r.numer, this->denomer);
    else return Rational((this->numer * r.denomer) - (r.numer * this->denomer), this->denomer * r.denomer);
}

Rational Rational::operator+(const Rational& r) {
    if (this->denomer == r.denomer) return Rational(this->numer + r.numer, this->denomer);
    else return Rational((this->numer * r.denomer) + (r.numer * this->denomer), this->denomer * r.denomer);
}

bool Rational::operator == (const Rational& r1)
{
    int a, b, c, d; //int, not rational

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r1.getnumer();
    d = r1.getdenomer();

    return ((a * d) == (c * b));
}

bool Rational::operator < (const Rational& r1)
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r1.getnumer();
    d = r1.getdenomer();

    return ((a * b) < (c * b));
}

bool Rational::operator <= (const Rational& r1)
{
    int a, b, c, d; //int, not rational

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r1.getnumer();
    d = r1.getdenomer();

    return ((a * b) <= (c * b));
}

bool Rational::operator > (const Rational& r1)
{
    int a, b, c, d; //int, not rational

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r1.getnumer();
    d = r1.getdenomer();

    return ((a * b) > (c * b));
}

bool Rational::operator >= (const Rational& r1)
{
    int a, b, c, d; //int, not rational

    a = getnumer();
    b = getdenomer();
    c = r1.getnumer();
    d = r1.getdenomer();

    return ((a * b) >= (c * b));
}
```

This should work now.